# Provide empty string as roslaunch argument substitution

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a `default.launch` file with some arguments and default values (strings).

I would like to substitute a default value with an empty string while launching, e.g.

```
roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:=""
```

But the substitution is ignored. Also ignored are:

```
roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:=''
roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:=" "
```

etc.

Working substitutions are:

```
roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:="!"
roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:='test'
```

etc.

How can I provide an *empty string* as an argument substitution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296116/provide-empty-string-as-roslaunch-argument-substitution/) by [artifactz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22331/artifactz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 119 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) on 2018-07-03**:
I've messed with this for a while and can't get it. You can set an empty string as the default value and that works. What are you trying to achieve with this? Would an empty string default work for you?

**Comment by [artifactz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22331/artifactz/) on 2018-07-05**:
Thank you for your feedback. E.g. I have an argument which defaults to `/sonar`, because that's the default sonar topic. An empty string disables sonar processing. I guess the easiest workaround would be creating a new launch file.

**Comment by [artifactz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22331/artifactz/) on 2018-07-05**:
I opened an [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1447).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[A friendly GitHub user reminded me](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1447#issuecomment-468243096), that in bash you use quotation marks to group space-separated strings as a single argument, so everything ROS receives is `roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:=`.

To keep the quotes, you can use single quotes around the double qoutes:

```
roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:='""'
```

---

Originally posted by [artifactz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22331/artifactz/) with karma: 119 on 2019-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xinwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/36542/xinwf/) on 2019-08-02**:
It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As aconkey said giving an empty string from the command line does not seem to work. I'm not sure this is the cleanest solution, but you could hack together the desired behavior to some extent with eval and an intermediate argument.
Something like this:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="arg1"           default="some_value"/>
    <arg name="arg1_helper"    default="$(eval '' if (arg1 == '!') else arg1)"/>

    <include file="$(find pkg)/launch/$(arg arg1_helper)_node.launch">
    </include>
</launch>
```

- 

```
roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:=!
```

arg1_helper will evaluate to "" and will try to launch pkg/launch/_node.launch

```
roslaunch pkg default.launch arg1:=some_other_value
```

arg1_helper will evaluate to "some_other_value" and will try to launch pkg/launch/some_other_value_node.launch

```
roslaunch pkg default.launch
```

arg1_helper will evaluate to the default value "some_value" and will try to launch pkg/launch/some_value_node.launch

The downsides to this approach would be that you have to have an extra argument in your launch files and instead of arg1:="" you would have to use arg1:=! (or what ever else you set eval to) to set the argument as an empty string.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artifactz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22331/artifactz/) on 2018-07-05**:
Thank you for your idea and your feedback. I guess I'm just going to create a simple launch file including `default.launch` and overriding the argument there.